# Synonyms of "caveat"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

What are some synonyms of *caveat?* Interestingly, I wasn't able to find any in the four (approximately) thesauruses which I searched. I'm trying to use it in the following context:

> The emperor did further women's rights, however, his new laws
>   contained certain ***_*__** (caveats) which favored men.

Comment: A caveat is a warning, not an exception. Maybe you're just looking for the -right- word, not a synonym?

Comment: As noted in my comment under Unreason's answer, it's possible that *caveats* is appropriate, but that the problem lies in *which favored men*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I don't think you are using [caveat](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/caveat#caveat_6) correctly, if we agree that it means:

> a warning of the limits of a particular agreement or statement

then your example is awkward and ambiguous.

> The emperor did further women's rights, however, his new laws contained certain **warnings of the limits** which favored men.

So, it is not really clear what you want there. I will propose a very common word as a substitute in this specific sentence

> The emperor did further women's rights, however, his new laws contained certain **limitations** which favored men.

(*stipulations*, *clauses* and *conditions* would work, too)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I was however, unaware that caveat was not a valid word for what I was looking for. Can you not say, "You may have this privilege but there is one caveat; XYZ"?

Comment: @XenElement: The example sentence in your comment is not as awkward as the example sentence in the text of your question. In your comment, you're saying "beware of the limitations of this privilege".  In your question, it's hard to tell exactly what you're saying, because a "law favoring women, with limitations" is not the same thing as a "law favoring men".  Even the limitations themselves would not usually be considered to favor men; they just serve to limit *how much* the law *favors women*.

Answer (score 3):

Also consider *provisos, [provisions](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/provision)*[1], *conditions, [clauses](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clause)*[2], *exceptions*, and *[loopholes](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/loophole)*[3].

[1] "*(law)* A clause in a legal instrument, a law, etc., providing for a particular matter; stipulation; proviso."

[2] "*(law)* A separate part of a contract, a will or another legal document."

[3]  "A method of escape, especially an ambiguity or exception in a rule that can be exploited in order to avoid its effect."

Comment: Special legal contexts aside, I'd say *proviso* is usually an exact synonym for *caveat*, in both meaning and style.

Answer (score 0):

How about *qualification*?  From Merriam-Webster:

> 1: a restriction in meaning or application : a limiting modification